# Jquery datepicker with entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, jquery, asp.net-ajax

```
        <form id="Form1" runat="server">
**<input type="text" id="DateInput" />**     
    <asp:Repeater ID="DataViewer" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style='border: 1px; width: 600px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;'>
                                <div style='float: left;'>
                                    <%# Eval("DriverName") %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>

                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

this is my function:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OrderDataRepository rep = new OrderDataRepository();

    var results = rep.GetAllOrderData().Where(x => x.POD_DATE == ????????????????).
                  GroupBy(o => o.User).
                  Select(g =>
                            new
                            {
                                DriverId = g.Key.Id,
                                DriverName = g.Key.Name,
                                OrderCount = g.Count(),
                                OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull = 
                                                  g.Count(o => o.RECEIVE_NAME != null)
                            }).ToList();

    DataViewer.DataSource = results;
    DataViewer.DataBind();
}
```

at the moment i get all the results from the table,
i want to add Datepicker for jQuery http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

```
  <script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

when user will pick a day it needs to load all the results for the day that the user picked

please show me how it should be done using jquery with entity framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a function in your repository some thing like:

```
Function SelectOrdersByDate(date as string) as ienumerable(of Order)
Using yourcontext as new context
Dim query = yourcontext.Orders.Where(function(o) o.OrderDate = date).ToList
return query
End Using
End Function
```

Then call this function via ajax/jquery

Comment: can you please show me how to use the ajax/jquery with this function?

Comment: I HAVE EDITED THE CODE SO IT WOULD BE MORE UNDERSTANDABLE